# C++/CLI typedef cliext LNK2022 error

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, cliext

If you write a C++/CLI application, and you attempt to use STL:CLR via cliext and you typedef for example a cliext map then you will find that it doesn't work due to a LNK2022 error.

Comment: Templates do not have external linkage.  News at eleven.  Never use std::clr, use Dictionary<> instead.

Comment: Hans would you like to post a formal answer below and elaborate so I can give you the points for this answer? I did update my answer due to your comment, but it would be more honest to flag your answer as the correct one. You could emphasize why the link error occurs and why Dictionary is better. Preferably minus the sarcasm. :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken in my original answer on how to mitigate the link error as pointed out by Hans in the comment above. Though, he does recommend using Dictionary instead, it is still possible to continue using cliext and solve the problem without unusual workarounds.

The actual answer is that templates do not allow external linkage. This means that somewhere I was using the cliext::map outside of my namespace. The moment that was eliminated, the link error goes away.

Comment: Side note: BEGIN_COMPANY_VIDEO_NAMESPACE is pure ugliness.

Comment: I think the prettiness of namespaces in general can be debated.